# BUILD FAILED : a module is not authorized to depend on itself: com.vaadin.external.atmosphere#atmosphere-compat-jbossweb;2.0.1-vaadin1

Tags: jenkins

my project is VaadinFramework based project.I was run build.xml file through jenkins.
i struck with error like this.

/build.xml:28: impossible to resolve dependencies:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: a module is not authorized to depend on itself: com.vaadin.external.atmosphere#atmosphere-compat-jbossweb;2.0.1-vaadin1,
if you know the answer please help me out

Answer (score 0):

the above three addons i was added in ivy.xml file.my problem was salved.
Becouse my project is vaadin based project.so it using vaadin dependencies in compile and runtime.
anyhow im also looking otherways to soughtout this problem inspite of  addons.